# Join Table with two polymorphic associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

is there a way in Rails to formulate an Association of TreeNodes for a join-table Tree that consists of the two polymorphic associations :parent and :children? Normally I only know of examples where one of the two columns is polymorphic and one is a foreign key.

```
class Tree < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :children, polymorphic: true
end
```

and then something like this

```
class TreeNode < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :trees

  has_one :parent
  has_many :children
end
```

I want to have a Tree consisting of TreeNodes of different classes.

Yours sincerely

Comment: Can you make your issue cleaner? You want to have a tree, a tree has many tree nodes, and a tree node can be partent or children of others tree nodes. Is right?

Comment: yep. but the module acts_as_tree for example only supports tree methods for a single class. i would like to be able to have, say, a Link-object the :child of a Post-object. E.g. objects of different classes in the :parent / :child - relationship.

Comment: Isn't it possible to have one :parent and one or multiple :children of different classes or the same class ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I miss your reply. Yes, you can. In your case, I think you need to add parent_id to tree_nodes table ? You can show me your schemas

Comment: Hello Thuy,

thank you for your reply. But I have the join table with the polymorphic :parent field, so there already is a parent_id (and a :parent_type fiel) right? Tried all compossible combinations of has_one, has_many and :as, :through, :source, :source_type but rails doesn't seem to "know" how to handle a join table with two polymorphic fields. One polymorphic field together with a froreign key: yes. It let me implement tags that way. It also knows a graph or tree with one class.  Neither exiges a double-polymorphic join-table.

Best wishes !